# How to click link from dropdown and display in textbox with live search then remove value when deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so here goes my best explanation:
I am looking to build a search bar that will have a default value of Current location.

[image: Current location]

My input field is as follows

```
     <div class="input-group col-sm-12">
        <label class="control-label" for="city"><h4>City</h4></label>
         <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg city" id="city" 
value="Current Location" name="city" autocomplete="off">
         </div>
         <div id="here"></div>
     </div>
```

I am using the code below to keep the default value of 'Current Location' in the text box so if the user clicks outside the text box when its empty the "**current location**" value will populate the text box. This part works great. Displays 'Current Location' when the text box is empty.

```
$('input.city').on('focus', function () {
            // On first focus, check to see if we have the default text saved
            // If not, save current value to data()
            if (!$(this).data('defaultText')) $(this).data('defaultText', 
    $(this).val());

            // check to see if the input currently equals the default before 
    clearing it
            if ($(this).val() == $(this).data('defaultText')) $(this).val('');
        });
        $('input.city').on('blur', function () {
            // on blur, if there is no value, set the defaultText
            if ($(this).val() == '') $(this).val($(this).data('defaultText'));
        });
```

Now when the user starts typing a location into the textbox, it does a live search and puts the values into a dropdown box. I have a textfile that i am using to test it below:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item city-link" id="1">San Jose</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item city-link" id="2">San Juan</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item city-link" id="3">San Julio</a>
</div>
```

Here is what the dropdown looks like, it also works well, and displays the proper data. What I need is to be able to make it scrollable if there are more than 5 locations:

[image: dropdown]

I am using jquery to grab the values from the text file but eventually will be the database.

```
 // Live search code for cities on advanced modal
    $("#city").keyup(function () {
         if (this.value.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById("#here").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        //Return value only after inputting 3 or more letters
        if (this.value.length < 4) return;
        //Show the values to the user
                $("#here").show();
                var x = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'test2.txt',
                    data: 'q=' + x,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#here").html(data);
                    }
                });
    });
```

What I am having an issue with... is that I want to allow the user to type a location into the input box, have suggestions dropdown in a div that show 5 values(links) and then a scroll bar with more values if needed, and then if the user clicks on one of those links it will fill the textbox with the value. but if they change their mind and delete the value in the input box, it will fill the input with the default value of Current location. Also with my current configuration, when I start deleting the value in the textbox, it does not update the dropdown list. Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
I'm no pro at Jquery and I welcome all criticism.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#city").keyup(function () {
     if (this.value.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("#here").innerHTML = "";
        this.value = "Current Location";
        return;
    }
    //Return value only after inputting 3 or more letters
    if (this.value.length < 4) return;
    //Show the values to the user
            $("#here").show();
            var x = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'test2.txt',
                data: 'q=' + x,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#here").html(data);
                }
            });
});
```

> Here you can try this code. when you remove all text from your text box than it's length will be 0 so after that you can set your default value to `Current Location` With this code.

Try it, It may helps you :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply Nirav...what i am looking for is a way to take the selected item from the dropdown list and put the value of that selection into the textbox.

Comment: I guess im looking for something similar to Ajax's live search but instead of the items in the dropdown linking to another page, it will just put the user selection into the text box so that it can be sent with the rest of the form later instead of updating immediately.